# Django with social auth: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, manytomanyfield

When trying to authenticate (create) a user in Django, I get the following error:

```
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use posts.set() instead.
```

I'm aware that there are similar questions to this on Stack overflow, and that according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

> [The model] needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
> ...
> You can’t associate it until it’s been saved.

However, since I'm using [Python Social Auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html), it creates the user in the backend, so I'm not able to save the user and modify the field later. (Although for me personally, I don't need to add anything to the many-to-many field when first creating the user)

Here's my code:

*models.py*

```py
...
from waters.models import Water

class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Water) # MANY TO MANY FIELD CAUSING ERROR
...
```

*oauth.py*

```py
from social_core.backends.oauth import BaseOAuth2

class <name>Oauth2(BaseOAuth2):
    name = "<name>"
    AUTHORIZATION_URL = "<url>"
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "<url>"
    ACCESS_TOKEN_METHOD = "POST"
    EXTRA_DATA = [("refresh_token", "refresh_token", True), ("expires_in", "expires")]

    def get_scope(self):
        return ["read"]

    def get_user_details(self, response):
        profile = self.get_json("<url>", params={"access_token": response["access_token"]})
        return {
            "id": profile["id"],
            "username": profile["username"],
            ...
        }

    def get_user_id(self, details, response):
        return details["id"]
```

How can I resolve this error without modifying any of the social auth source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bypass the error by extending the social authentication pipeline ([documentation](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html)). First, I made a method to create the user appropriately to bypass the error (as stated in the answer linked in the question):

*authentication/pipeline.py*

```py
from authentication.models import User

def create_user(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    u = User()
    for k, v in kwargs["details"].items():
        setattr(u, k, v)
    u.save()
    # Optionally update many to many field here
```

and plopped that before social auth's `create_user` method:

*settings.py*

```py
...
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email",
    "authentication.pipeline.create_user", #ADDED
    "social_core.pipeline.user.create_user",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user",
    "social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data",
)
...
```